# What is the default editor for git on windows, and where is the executable?

Tags: git, powershell, editor

I just have the official git for windows 2.7.2 installed on my new windows. When I executed `git commit` on PowerShell without `-m`, I found the default editor is accidentally handy. So I would like to use it outside `git`, by adding it to the `PATH` environment variable, but I don't know its name.

I'm not sure if the editor is from any other environments, since it's a new win10 system I just installed `PuTTY` and `MinGW`.

I have checked `git config --global core.editor` and other git setting files but the editor entry is always empty.

Could anyone tell me how to use whatever that editor is outside `git commit`?

Comment: Under linux, it's usually whatever is stored in `$EDITOR`. Just type `echo $EDITOR` and you'll see. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you. I tried echo $EDITOR in Ubuntu with git 1.9.1 installed but unfortunately it's empty.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)).

(It was on my PC)

Although, I suspect it's entirely dependent on your system.

Comment: I've searched mingw64/bin folder under git and couldn't find any Vi-like. It seems deeply integrated with git.

Comment: According to: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration
It will be Vi unless something else is defined. Are you sure you haven't got another command line editor? Emacs? Nano?

Comment: The only editor I'm currently using is Visual Studio Code, so I'm looking for an command line editor on windows. Like I said I'm not sure if PuTTY or MinGW brings any, since I just have those two command line tools installed... Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that every installation is different, especially now that this question is a little bit old, but for the Git bundled with Visual Studio 2017 (Windows 10) at the time of this writing, it is definitely Vim and the binary is located at:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vim
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#idp31108464), in fact it's `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` by default, or Vi otherwise.

So if you want to use a Vi-like, you can use a GUI like [GVim](http://www.vim.org/download.php) in Windows.

Comment: In PowerShell I did 'ls env:' but nothing like '$EDITOR' or' $VISUAL'. I just found the default editor is exactly what I want so I wouldn't bother to install others separately...

Answer (score 0):

In 2019/2020 at least for me it the default is nano in

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\nano.exe
```

You can run in powershell with

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\nano.exe' <filename>
```

note AFAICT vim is still in there too but nano is arguably more beginner friendly since it is less modal, uses slightly more standard keys and lists the important ones at the bottom